# Ubuntu : How Uninstall PowerBroker Identity Services

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, uninstallation

I've install pbis (PowerBroker Identity Services) in my ubuntu using the .sh install. And now i want to remove pbis, but i don't see how to do this.

Comment: thanks! this q&a should be moved to https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok i've found how, Docs is stored in this directory : /opt/pbis/docs

Simply run these two command to leave domain and uninstall :

> sudo /opt/pbis/bin/domainjoin-cli leave
>
> sudo /opt/pbis/bin/uninstall.sh uninstall

Voilà!